# How to creat a clickable link in a textview?

Tags: android

I am trying to create a clickable link in a textview in a fragment. I think the emulator sees my string as a link but I can't make it clickable. Any suggestions?

In xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewLink"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="all"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:text="@string/link_to_the_website"
    android:textColor="#329da8"
    android:textSize="17sp" />
```

In fragment

```
linkText.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
linkText.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"C:\\Users\\andra\\Documents\\AndroidStudioProjects\\ResurseAndroid\\index.html\"> Read more here</a>"));

linkText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        linkText = v.findViewById(R.id.textViewLink);
        linkText.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        linkText.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"C:\\Users\\andra\\Documents\\AndroidStudioProjects\\ResurseAndroid\\index.html\"> Read more here</a>"));
    }
});
```

In `strings.xml`

```
<string name="link_to_the_website">
    <a href="C:\Users\andra\Documents\AndroidStudioProjects\ResurseAndroid\index.html"> Read more here</a>
</string>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove `android:autoLink="all"` and it should work. When you use `setMovementMethod`, `android:autoLink` is not needed as it will override the `setMovementMethod`.

Also I'm not sure why you are setting the `TextView`s link in 3 different ways remove the:

1. Using `@string` on the XML
2. Programmatically via code
3. In the `onClick`

Firstly I don't think the `onClick` is needed and secondly pick a choice either set it via

```
android:text="@string/link_to_the_website"
```

**OR**

```
linkText.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"C:\\Users\\andra\\Documents\\AndroidStudioProjects\\ResurseAndroid\\index.html\"> Read more here</a>"));
```

and not both.

If you use the programmatic method the`fromHtml` method you are using is deprecated you should instead use `fromHtml(String source, int flags)` like this:

```
linkText.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=https://google.com> Read more here</a>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
```

notice the extra parameter `Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY`

or like this if you are targeting devices less than Android Nougat (API Level 24):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    linkText.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=https://google.com> Read more here</a>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
} else {
    linkText.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=https://google.com> Read more here</a>"));
}
```

Lastly I'm not sure linking to a hardcoded path on your C dive will work, I tested the above using an actual website i.e.:

```
linkText.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=https://google.com> Read more here</a>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
```

Comment: It worked!Thank you!  I removed android:autoLink="all", onClick and set the link programmatically via code. Also after the changes it wouldn't work with my hardcoded path.

Comment: Glad to help and yes that hard-coded path to your C drive will never work, the emulator doesn't know how to access it, imagine your physical device no ways it would. You either need an actual website or perhaps opening it from the phones external storage or something